# Logwatch Unmatched Entries for named connection refused resolving

Tags: bind, logwatch

Using the default setup of Logwatch on RHEL 6 and the caching name server (BIND 9) package, my daily logwatch reports are filled with unmatched entries regarding DNS server errors.

What do I need to change in the configuration in order to either hide those errors or do I need to modify the RHEL6 options for their caching name server package (/etc/named.caching-nameserver.conf).

```
--------------------- Named Begin ------------------------ 

 **Unmatched Entries**
    connection refused resolving '1.146.219.117.bb.barracudacentral.org/A/IN': 75.101.143.130#53: 1 Time(s)
    connection refused resolving '1.146.219.117.bb.barracudacentral.org/A/IN': 75.101.148.228#53: 1 Time(s)
    connection refused resolving '1.186.145.75.bb.barracudacentral.org/A/IN': 75.101.143.130#53: 1 Time(s)
    connection refused resolving '1.186.145.75.bb.barracudacentral.org/A/IN': 75.101.148.228#53: 1 Time(s)
    connection refused resolving '1.240.27.165.bb.barracudacentral.org/A/IN': 75.101.143.130#53: 1 Time(s)
    connection refused resolving '1.240.27.165.bb.barracudacentral.org/A/IN': 75.101.148.228#53: 1 Time(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using Amazon AWS to host this machine; apparently, there are nameservers that refuse queries from AWS.

I think you have to use Amazon's provided nameservers instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're running your own email server, and using something like SpamAssassin to filter email.  This looks like it's trying to reverse-resolve a DNSBL to check whether or not the address exist.  Barracuda requires an account now.